# Android - Set parent activity android manifest

Tags: java, android, android-intent, back

I have 3 activities A, B, C. And I want to set them in a certain hierarchy and use the setParentActivity so I can get the default android back button automatically. So first off if there is a way to get the default android back button that would solve my problem.

I have download the android developer tools icons. And there are back button but not like this one and then i have to use actionBar.setIcon('icBackButton') so I can not set my own icon. I am talking about this back button if you are not sure what I am talking about. This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I have tried, the other problem with this is I don't want all the text to be selected when back is pressed it should just be the back button.

[image]

I can use setParentActivity to do this but when I have tried I haven't been able to get it to work correctly. Here is how I want the hierarchy to work.

[image]

If here is what the visual is saying A is launcher activity and it can go to B or C. And then B can go to C. And at C when back is hit I always want it to go back to the perivious activity.

I how this all makes sense I tried to explain it clearly as I could.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, and then override

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This way, pressing the up button will always act as pressing the back button, which is exactly the behaviour you have described.

For the title to not be selected, you could put a custom TextView as the title instead of the built in one and use that, but that would make the clicking of the Up button non-trivial (since it goes against the design guidelines), so I suggest not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

1) You can create a **BaseActivityC**. Then you can create Activity **AC** that extends BaseActivityC and Activity **BC** that extends BaseActivityC. 
In the manifest file set android:parentActivityName="com.packagename.activities.AC" for the MainActivity A and android:parentActivityName="com.packagename.activities.BC" for the MainActivity A.
When creating the res/layout file for BaseActivityC, you should have two more layouts **ac.xml** and **bc.xml**.  Each of them should include the baseLayout () and of course set the **tools:context=".AC"** and **tools:context=".BC"** in each of the layouts.

2) Maybe passing a class parameter **A.class** or **B.class** to Activity **C** and in **C** you can handle onBackPressed by checking the instanceOf A or B.

Hope that helps!